# Lumenworks CsvReader Exception

Tags: c#, csv, lumenworks

I need to parse a csv file and import it into a oracle database table. I use the Lumenworks Framework with this code:

```
using (CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(sFile), true))
{
     Console.WriteLine("test3");                       
}
```

But if I run the code, the following exception appears:

> Application: Application.exe
>
> Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>
> Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>
> Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
>
> Stack:
>      at Application.Program.Main(System.String[])

But the weird thing is, if I only execute the `new Streamreader(sFile)` part and write this on the console, no exception appears. I already debugged the sFile and this is a valid path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What a mistake. After hours I realized that the Lumenworks.dll wasn't copied to the application.exe..

Another exception than `System.IO.FileNotFoundException` would be truly grateful.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `new StreamReader(sFIle);` and the file does not exists it will throw an exception. The path could be a valid formatted path, but if the file is not there then the exception thrown, `FileNotFoundException`, would make perfect sense.

Check to make sure that the file exists at the specified path before trying to open the stream.

```
if (File.Exists(sFIle) {
    using (CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(sFile), true)) {
         Console.WriteLine("test3");                       
    } 
}
```

Comment: I already tried to check if the file exist like you did in your code, but the exception still appear. Also it looks like the code: new StreamReader(sFile) works fine and the CsvReader is my problem